# While starting A jetty server, Failed to instantiate SLF4J LoggerFactory

Tags: java, eclipse, logging, jetty, m2e

Context:

I am using eclipse 3.7 (Java EE version) with M2E on a Linux machine.

When I try to run a jetty server from the run/debug menu I get this error:

```
Failed to instantiate SLF4J LoggerFactory
Reported exception:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.bind(LoggerFactory.java:121)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.performInitialization(LoggerFactory.java:111)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:268)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:241)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:254)
    at com.ning.http.client.Realm$RealmBuilder.<clinit>(Realm.java:250)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initializeImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:200)
    at org.sonatype.aether.connector.async.AsyncRepositoryConnector.getRealm(AsyncRepositoryConnector.java:167)
    at org.sonatype.aether.connector.async.AsyncRepositoryConnector.createConfig(AsyncRepositoryConnector.java:227)
    at org.sonatype.aether.connector.async.AsyncRepositoryConnector.<init>(AsyncRepositoryConnector.java:149)
    at org.sonatype.aether.connector.async.AsyncRepositoryConnectorFactory.newInstance(AsyncRepositoryConnectorFactory.java:110)
    at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultRemoteRepositoryManager.getRepositoryConnector(DefaultRemoteRepositoryManager.java:333)
    at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:456)
    at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:220)
    at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:197)
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:268)
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.readArtifactDescriptor(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:173)
    at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultDependencyCollector.process(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:419)
    at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultDependencyCollector.process(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:533)
    at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultDependencyCollector.process(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:533)
    at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultDependencyCollector.collectDependencies(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:243)
    at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultRepositorySystem.collectDependencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:345)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.java:119)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.getDependencies(LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:165)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.resolveProjectDependencies(LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:104)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.ensureDependenciesAreResolved(MojoExecutor.java:258)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:201)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.executeForkedExecutions(MojoExecutor.java:365)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:199)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:319)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:534)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder
    at java.lang.ClassNotFoundException.<init>(ClassNotFoundException.java:76)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:38)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:244)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:230)
    ... 51 more
```

I know that this means I am missing a class on the classpath. The trouble is it shouldn't be looking for this class (I am not using it).

Running the jetty server from the Linux console works fine.

To make things more bizarre if I run it as an external tool (within eclipse), and then connect to the debugging session it runs just fine. The bizarre part is that if I shut this server down and then run/debug in the original way (the way that first issued an error) it now runs fine.

One more piece of possibly relevant information is that the Eclipse project configurations where pulled from a repository, and the Windows users do not see this issue.

What is going on here? Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: Maybe you are not using it, but Jetty is using slf4j. Are you sure all relevant libraries that are used when run from commandline are also on the classpath when run from Eclipse?

Comment: Your stacktrace is missing some lines: Which class calls `org.slf4j.*`?

Comment: Aaron, I added the full stack trace.

Comment: I have tried uninstalling the optional package in M2E `m2e - slf4j over logback logging (Optional)` but that didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out. So I am posting this answer for anyone having the same trouble.

I was using the IBM JDK and as soon as I switched to the Oracle JDK this issue went away. So the answer is to switch to a different version of the JDK/JVM that you are using.